# If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are real functions with $f(x)+g(x)=\sin x$, then can we say that they each have the form $a\sin(bx+c)+d$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two real functions. If $f(x) + g(x) = \sin(x)$, then  can we confidently say that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions of the type $a\cdot \sin(b\cdot x+c)+d$? If not, then what are some counter examples?

Edit: not rational functions but real functions

Comment: Certainly not.  $\sin(bx+c)+d$ is not a rational function.

Comment: My bad, fixed it.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac 12 e^{ix}, g(x) = \frac 12 e^{ix}, f(x) + g(x) = \cos x$

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=e^{x}, g(x)=\sin(x)-e^{x}$

Comment: Of course, missed that simple answer. But as a further question, what if it is $f(x) + f(x+1) = sin(x)$

Comment: Take any function $g$ on $[0,1)$. Define $f$ to be $g$ on $[0,1)$, $\sin(x-1)-g(x-1)$ on $[1,2)$, and so on.